# In Linux, how do I write a script that cats all .js files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

In my directory, I want to run the script.
The script should take all .js files (and recursively as well), and merge them together into 1  file and spit out that file.

How can I write this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find somedir/ -name '*.js' -exec cat {} +
```

Comment: I'm used to putting \; at the end of exec. What does + do?

Comment: @vmpstr: It packs as many arguments as possible in the command instead of running it with only one.

Comment: How do I add a line break after each file? that it cats?  I think it's freaking out and not working.

Comment: JavaScript shouldn't need any blank lines separating the individual parts.

Comment: @TIMEX 
`find ./ -name '*.js' | xargs -I jsFile bash -c "cat jsFile;echo \"___________\";"`
This is one way of doing the same

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -e 'BEGIN{o=open("out","w")};Dir["**/*.js"].each{|x|o.write(open(x).read()+"\n")};END{o.close()}'
```